# how to play video in MPMoviePlayerController using this URL"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPUWNcGDyvM&feature=player_embedded"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

i want to play the video of this URL http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPUWNcGDyvM&feature=player_embedded where i PAUSE last time... i can play the video but when i leave this page and come back to see this video this will start from previously.But i want to show this video with continue where i had Paused last. CODE..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
 player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%@video.mp4",urlVideo]]];   
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];
//---play movie---
[player prepareToPlay];
[player pause];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 367);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];   
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

my movieFinishedCallbackm method is:-

```
- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:player];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MPMoviePlayerController you can implement the MPMediaPlayback protocol, so on your player, you can just send a pause message:

```
[myMoviePlayer pause];
```

Use viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear to pause the video and viewWillAppear or viewdidAppear to resume playing it.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [myMoviePlayer play];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [myMoviePlayer pause];
}
```